# Post Thumbnail: Is there a possibility to add a description to the meta box?

Tags: wp-admin, metabox, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, description

Probably many of you are using the Post Thumbnail feature: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

I wonder if it is possible to add a description to the post thumbnail meta box in the admin area. Such as: ***Please only upload quadratic images*** or ***Minimum size 250x250***? Is there some kind of hook, filter or option?

Comment: Before I start copying already existing code I would suggest you take a look at this answer from [@Howdy_McGee](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125167/42959) and up-vote that answer when it is what you where looking for.  Or even better take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43107282). Probably exact what you are looking for if I understand your question well. *sorry I deleted my answer exactly at the moment you responded.*

Comment: @Jerry.S It does not exactly answer my question as I wanted to add an extra labe inside the box. But for my purpose it is enough to add this information to the existing labels - (nvm repostet comment afterwards)